# getting Error: Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have already deleted the package.json and then run "npm install" again but the error persists

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function (req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`starting app on: ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Can I have package.json dependencies list?